# Could the default value of a TensorFlow op attribute be NaN or Inf?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

My case is to add `vmin` and `vmax` attributes to the [TensorFlow ImageSummary Op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/ops/logging_ops.cc#L79). Here is my code for this op registration:

```
REGISTER_OP("ImageSummary")
    .Input("tag: string")
    .Input("tensor: T")
    .Output("summary: string")
    .Attr("vmin: float = NaN")
    .Attr("vmax: float = NaN")
    .Attr("clip: bool = false")
    .Attr("max_images: int >= 1 = 3")
    .Attr("T: {uint8, float, half, float64} = DT_FLOAT")
    .Attr(
        "bad_color: tensor = { dtype: DT_UINT8 "
        "tensor_shape: { dim { size: 4 } } "
        "int_val: 255 int_val: 0 int_val: 0 int_val: 255 }")
    .SetShapeFn(shape_inference::ScalarShape);
```

Although this works for [the C++ test code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/summary_image_op_test.cc), there were some errors when building the whole project:

```
bazel-out/darwin-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/cc/ops/logging_ops.h:237:19: error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'float' with an lvalue of type 'float (const char *)'
    float vmin_ = nanf;
                  ^~~~
bazel-out/darwin-opt/genfiles/tensorflow/cc/ops/logging_ops.h:238:19: error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'float' with an lvalue of type 'float (const char *)'
    float vmax_ = nanf;
```

I think it should be `float vmin = nanf("")` and `float vmax = nanf("")` in `logging_ops.h`. Is this an issue in TensorFlow compiler? Or I may have some misunderstanding of the grammar for setting the default value?

Are there any suggestions for my case?